# How to make nginx rewrite rules work?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to add some rewrite rules like this.

```
location / { 
    autoindex   on; 
    root   /Users/guest/Projects/demo/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~* ^/signin {
        rewrite ^/signin(.*)$ /account/page/signin$1 break;
    }   
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)  /index.php?$1 last;
    }   
}
```

I want it would works as these steps as long as I type an url like "http://host/signin".

step 1 : rewrite this url to "http://host/account/page/signin"
step 2 : rewrite it with the rule "rewrite ^/(.*)  /index.php?$1 last;"

But now, the step 1 is working, but it seems that the rule is stop at there.

I tried some different way to do, such as

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
     rewrite ^/signin(.*)$ /account/page/signin$1;
     rewrite ^/(.*)  /index.php?$1 last;
}
```

or

```
rewrite ^/signin(.*)$ /account/page/signin$1;

if (!-e $request_filename) {
     rewrite ^/(.*)  /index.php?$1 last;
}
```

Sometimes I can get this error from log :

```
open() "/Users/guest/Projects/demo/public/account/page/signin" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

How can I make it work as I want?

Comment: change it to your requirement ``location /signin/ {
index index.php index.html;
rewrite ^/signin/([^/]+)(/?)$ /signin?login=$1 last;
}``

Comment: @Rajlaksh  thanks a bunch. but it still doesn't work.